# atp splitable feature AUTOSAR

Tags: autosar

This is about splittable feature of AUTOSAR where one composition can be split across multiple files.
Before implementing I just wanted to learn a bit more on this.
like how the input model looks like or the metamodel itself.
Can someone point to a location or provide a sample XML file to start the same.
Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information in the specification of the AUTOSAR Generic Structure Template. Beside a detailed description of how the meta-model is affected, this document also explains splitable models by means of examples.