# ARXML example of atp.splitkey in AUTOSAR

Tags: autosar

As per my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933032/atp-splitable-feature-autosar) I got the clue to understand ATP Splitability feature of AUTOSAR. But I don't find any link how the splitability is presented in an arxml file. Any info on this? Because this aplitability is a stereotype and has present in annotated format. currently I am lacking the info on how the stereotype elements looks inside an AUTOSAR ARXML or arxml file.

Answer (score 1):

The stereotype isn't represented at all in an ARXML file. The stereotype just indicates to creators of an AUTOSAR tool that tools loading the model shall accept the existence of the same model element (aggregated or referenced in the stereotyped role in the meta-model) in two different ARXML files loaded into the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It's getting clearer now but I could not understand where to use atp.SplitKey:

Comment: e.g. The AUTOSAR_TPS_ECUC_configuration doc specifies whole list of splitable Elcment ->Splitkey e.g Arpackage.arpackage <->shortName,variationPoint,shortLabel Not sure where I need to provide this splitKey info. Do I need to just provide this dynamically during model loading in the tool?

Comment: You don't. This is just a piece of support for the tool implementer about the nature of the splitable element. Please read the standard specification again.